# Excel PERCENTRANK.INC in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, excel-formula

Is there an exact way to clone the PERCENTRANK.INC function of Excel in Javascript ?
I wrote my own and also tried to use the following libraries - the results don't always match.

https://github.com/formulajs/formulajs

https://github.com/malcolmvr/percentile-rank

FormulaJS comes close to Excel's output but it still has differences.
In the table below the 'RAW Data' is the original array, the second column is values which I am trying to compare with the data in the first column using the PERCENTRANK.INC function.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/percentrank-inc-function-149592c9-00c0-49ba-86c1-c1f45b80463a

[image]

Is there a way to get the exact results as in Excel for this function. I am also sharing my Node code to experiment with the function.

```
const formularjs = require('@formulajs/formulajs');

let array =[71,13,23,32,45,99,103,71,43,11,91,21,45,45,89,66,41,29,66,63];
let compare_array =[11,19,17,31,32,43,71,63,35,13,73,74,81,100,13,41,31,29,31,33];


compare_array.forEach(function(n){

     let pr = formularjs.PERCENTRANKINC(array,n,3);
     console.log(pr); 
 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the discrepancy, using your code from

> https://github.com/malcolmvr/percentile-rank/blob/master/lib/index.js

I rewrote it in VB, with a tweak to recreate the issue.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
For i = 1 To 20
Cells(i, 4) = prc(Cells(i, 2), True) / 19
Next i
For i = 1 To 20
If Cells(i, 4) = 0 Then Cells(i, 4) = ipp(Cells(i, 2))
Next i
End Sub

Function prc(v, j)
For i = 1 To 20
If v = Cells(i, 1) Then
prc = i - 1
If j Then i = 20 ' if j is true then return first value
End If
Next i
End Function

Function ipp(v)
For i = 1 To 19
If v > Cells(i, 1) And v < Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
x1 = Cells(i, 1)
x2 = Cells(i + 1, 1)
y1 = prc(x1, False) / 19
y2 = prc(x2, False) / 19
ipp = ((x2 - v) * y1 - (x1 - v) * y2) / (x2 - x1)
End If
Next i
End Function
```

Screenshot

[image: percentrank.inc]

The first column is the sorted raw data - your function doesn't work unless this is the case. The second is the test values, the third is Excel's `PERCENTRANK.INC`, and the fourth is my function (to 3dp, not 3sf).

The issue comes from data with multiple entries, for example `71` appears twice in the raw data.

When direct matches are being found, the **first** value found is returned. When the data is being interpolated, the **last** value is returned.

This is addressed in my code using boolean flag `j` to determine which value (first or last) is to be returned.

Comment: Thank you so much for identifying the issue for me. I made the change and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on @JMP's answer above but a node/JS version.

The below is a rewritten version of 'percentile-rank' library.

```
const percentRank = (arr, value, bool) => {

    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

    let percValue;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === value) {
            percValue = i / (arr.length - 1);;
            if (bool) return percValue;
        }
    }
    return percValue;


    // calculate value using linear interpolation
    let x1, x2, y1, y2;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < value && value < arr[i + 1]) {
            x1 = arr[i];
            x2 = arr[i + 1];
            y1 = percentRank(arr, x1, false);
            y2 = percentRank(arr, x2, false);
            return (((x2 - value) * y1 + (value - x1) * y2)) / (x2 - x1);
        }
    }

    throw new Error('Out of bounds');
};
```

In the below code we call the newly written function.

```
let array =[71,13,23,32,45,99,103,71,43,11,91,21,45,45,89,66,41,29,66,63];
let compare_array =[11,19,17,31,32,43,71,63,35,13,73,74,81,100,13,41,31,29,31,33];


compare_array.forEach(function(n){

  var array1 =[];

  array.forEach(function(a){
    if(!isNaN(a) ) array1.push(a);
  })

     let pr = percentRank(array1,n,true);
     console.log(pr.toFixed(3));

});
```

The answers match what we get in the Excel Percentrank.inc